# Spell checking in Xcode, no suggestions?

Tags: xcode

Is there an easy way to get suggested corrections when spell checking a text document in Xcode 14?

I have check-as-you-type turned on, and redlining is appearing - which is nice because it did not previously turn on by default and I found lots of typos in my documentation.

However, when I right-click on a redlined word, no suggestions appear, all I get is Ignore and Learn. Normally, suggested replacements would appear above those entries.

Even more curious, if I go to Edit->Format->Spelling->Show Spelling, it does not have the mis-spelled work in the edit box, it's just empty.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Xcode 15. It may be in 14 as well.

Go to: **Edit -> Format -> Spelling and Grammar -> Show Spelling and Grammar**.
Then you can run through the document, get issues highlighted, and are able to choose replacements.

Another possible solution (specialized on comments) could be [this project](https://github.com/velyan/Comment-Spell-Checker).

Comment: So the right-click simply doesn't work in Xcode? That seems mighty odd.